# Sumif by VBA using the previous cell of the previous column always as parameter until the end of the column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm trying to make a `SUMIF` using VBA to sum the values until the end of the column, always changing the criteria of the sum using the previus cell of the previous column as parameter.

```
    Sub SOMA()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("E1")
r = ("E1" + 1)
LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
    Range("F1:F" & LastRow) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("B:B"), Range(r))
    
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

the `r` should always change to E1,E2,E3,etc. until end of the column. Because the `E` is always a new criteria.

---

Edit 1:

[image]

Sorry for my bad explaning, what i expected was make a `SUMIF(A:A;E1;B:B)` row by row placing the values on column `F` always changing the criteria to `E2`,`E3`,`E4`,etc. until the end of the column `F`.

Answer (score 1):

### VBA SumIfs

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SOMA()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Range("B" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sws.Range("B2:B" & slRow) ' Criteria Range
    Dim ssrg As Range: Set ssrg = sws.Range("A2:A" & slRow) ' Sum Range
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Range("E" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dws.Range("E2:E" & dlRow) ' Criteria Range
    Dim dsrg As Range: Set dsrg = dws.Range("F2:F" & dlRow) ' Sum Range
    Dim dcOffset As Long: dcOffset = dsrg.Column - dcrg.Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dcCell As Range ' Criteria Cell
    
    ' Loop.
    For Each dcCell In dcrg.Cells
        dcCell.Offset(, dcOffset).Value = Application.SumIfs(ssrg, scrg, dcCell)
    Next dcCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Soma is done.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check my `Edit 1`

Answer (score 0):

From what’s in your code I’m assuming:

1. column E is being SUMIF’d
2. column A is the range being assessed for the SUMIF
3. column B is providing the criteria for the SUMIF
4. the SUMIF value is being output to column F

This is how I’d do it…

```
Sub Soma()

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim r_A As Range, r_B As Range, r_E As Range, r_F As Range

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

For i = 0 To ActiveSheet.Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Set r_A = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(i, 0))
    Set r_B = Range("B1").Offset(i, 0)
    Set r_E = Range(Range("E1"), Range("E1").Offset(i, 0))
    Set r_F = Range("F1").Offset(i, 0)

    r_F = wf.SumIf(r_A, r_B, r_E)

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Exist `Dim wf as Application.WorksheetFunction`? Excel flagged an error

Comment: Maybe is `set WorksheetFunction` also i guess it's wrong `For i = 0 to ActiveSheet.Range(“E1048576”).End(xlup).Row - 1`. Can you check please?

Comment: Yeah, should have included a line stating    
  "Set wf = WorksheetFunction"
soz, wrote the code on the phone and didn't check it.

Comment: What's the other issue you're having? Do you have the sheet selected?

Comment: Please check my `Edit 1` and fix your code to stay correct for who see

Comment: Hi @Black Mamba, I've updated the code to include what I missed. I've also found the cause of the other issue you mentioned.  It turns out that the quotation marks produced by my iphone are not recognised by VBA as quotation marks - so a learning for me too.  In any event, I've updated the script to remedy both issues and I've tested it so it should work for you now.  Let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: I'll just add that if you are interested in a "FillDown" version of the formula, rather than VBA, you should be able to use "=SUMIFS($E$1:E1,$A$1:A1,B1)" in cell F1, which you can then FillDown as required.

Comment: Thanks for fixing! But `For i = 0 To ActiveSheet.Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1` is still flagging as incorrect.

Comment: Also i just fixed your `SUMIF`: `=SUMIF(A:A,E1,B:B)`.

Comment: The code works for me. What error are you getting? Why don’t you share your workbook and I’ll have a look at it.

Comment: Regarding the SUMIF formula: 1) I used SUMIFS,

Comment: Regarding the SUMIF formula: 1) I used SUMIFS, not SUMIF, but that’s fine if there’s only one condition which there is, 2) the formula you wrote won’t provide a cumulative summation, it will provide the same summed total in every row each time the condition is matched, is that what you want? 3) the code I wrote aligns with the formula I wrote, not the one you wrote, if you want it fixed, please specify what column is being summed, what column is being assessed, what column contains the condition being used for the assessment, and whether you want a cumulative summation ?

Comment: I wrote the above without noticing your Edit 1, so all is answered except whether you want cumulative summation?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Well, columns `A` and `B` never change, Both are used to find the total value of the cell in the `E` column. Example.: `SUMIF(A:A,E1,B:B)`, `SUMIF(A:A,E2,B:B)`, `SUMIF(A:A,E3,B:B)`, etc. Until the last row. The output values has to be outputed in the `F` columns, `F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,etc...` Did you understand?

Comment: That does make sense. Based upon your comment, the SUMIF'd values are always totals of everything in column A (when the criteria in E matches the values column B).  That means that the same Total will appear in every cell in column F each time the same criteria (in E) exists.  Thus, the implication is that the sumifs are not cumulative. Before re-writing the code, would you mind confirming that this is what you want; i.e. that the sumif'd values are not cumulative?

Comment: Well my friend, i guess is better show than explain. Sorry for my bad english. Just uploaded my file for you check what i need.... also I took advantage and put another column to do the sum too. Please if you can check it: https://easyupload.io/8olwd1
My Excel is Portuguese, so maybe you need to change `SOMASE` to `SUMIF`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want multiple `SUMIFS` in column F where column E has the criteria. If so you don't need a loop, you can just enter the formula in F1 and use `FILLDOWN` to complete the rest

```
Sub SOMA()

Dim LastRow as Long

LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
Range("F1") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("B:B"), Range("E1"))
Range("F1:F"&LastRow).FillDown    
     
End Sub
```

Comment: No, the criteria will always change until the end of the column. E1 is the first criteria, then come E2,E3,E4,etc. until the end.